# How to compare map values in loop with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops, dictionary, key-value

Say I have

```
const food = new Map();
const max = 0;
food.set(hotdogs, 2);
food.set(pizza, 8);
```

I'd like to compare the values in my map to other values in my map, (for example: which is larger, 8 or 2? ), and execute code based on that comparison. I know that `for(let [k,v] of foods)` will loop through all keys and values, but how do I compare those to other keys and values in the same map? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you have an array of tuples? Can you show us an example data?

Comment: Use nested loops.

Comment: `for(let k,v of map)` is not valid JavaScript. You're mixing JS and Python.

Comment: I've edited the OP to show example data. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: It isn't any clearer; the open question is just what you want to *do* with this data.

Comment: @ScottHunter I want to set a variable "max" to the larger of the two values in my map "foods."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `Math.max()`, spread syntax and `map()`:

```js
let myMap = new Map();
myMap.set('hotdogs', 2);
myMap.set('pizza', 8);
var max = Math.max(...[...myMap].map(i => i[1]));
console.log(max);
```